# Dataframe type changes when returned in a list from a function

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

I generate two dataframes in a function and return them in a list

```
summarize_responses <- function(df, descriptor, subsetBy){
  .
  .

  df_sum           <- as.data.frame(df_sum)  
  df_sum_transpose <- as.data.frame(df_sum_transpose)
  
  return_list <- list(df_sum, df_sum_transpose)
  return(return_list)
}
```

In my main routine, I collect these dataframes as follows:

```
df_lst <- summarize_responses(df, INDEX_SCORES_BREAKOUTS[i],  DAILY_INDEX_SCORES)
df_a   <- df_lst[1]
df_b   <- df_lst[2]
```

but if I type

```
    Browse[2]> class(df_a)
    [1] "list"
    Browse[2]> typeof(df_a)
    [1] "list"
```

I expect that df_a and df_b will be dataframes based on the fact that I have forced them to be dataframes in `summarize_responses`.  But something has gone wrong here. While it's easy enough to fix by typing

```
df_a   <- as.data.frame(df_lst[1])
df_b   <- as.data.frame(df_lst[2])
```

I'd like to understand why my dataframes turned into lists.

Thanks in advance for an explanation

Thomas Philips

Comment: Use `[[`, `df_a   <- df_lst[[1]]`

Answer (score 1):

When you have list of dataframes, using single bracket (`[`) to access element in a list always give you a list back. Consider this example :

```
df_lst <- list(mtcars, iris)
class(df_lst[1])
#[1] "list"
```

This is because using `[` , you can select more than 1 element from the list.

```
df_lst[1:2]
```

If you want to access the dataframe use `[[`

```
class(df_lst[[1]])
#[1] "data.frame"
```

This Q & A can be helpful as well. [The difference between bracket [ ] and double bracket [[ ]] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)

Comment: Thanks a mill - it's clear now!